# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined-React error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am fetching the data from database of users list using axios. I have install axios for sending data which is working fine,while fetching the data I am getting error:"Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

below is my code of users.js

```
export default class users extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Users: []
        };
    }
    getUsersData() {
        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:8080/users-react/api/contact/users.php`, {})
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data
                console.log(data)
                const users = data.map(u =>
                    <div>
                     <p>{u.name}</p>
                    <p>{u.email}</p>
                    </div>
                    )
                    this.setState({users})})
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
   }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getUsersData()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.users}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Please let me know what mistake i did,I am new in React

Comment: What do you get on your console form the `console.log(data)`? and why are you passing the empty object to the `axios.get()`?

Comment: In console getting data. Map undef error

Comment: put `this` becfore `axios` e.g. `this.axios`

Comment: Getting now this error"Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Comment: before that in console getting data.map is not a function

Comment: have you installed axios? if you have installed you should import it to your component  at the top like `import axios from 'axios'`

Comment: yes I installed,now resolve

Comment: I am glade that your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

change the code for map function,now working fine:

```
posts.map(post => {
              const { user_id, name, email } = post;
              return (
                <div key={user_id}>
                  <h2>{name}</h2>
                  <p>{email}</p>
                  <hr />
                </div>
              );
        })
```